# Data-binding between ngInclude and ngView

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, scope

I want to make a sidebar with list item that can be dynamically changed based on the settings page.

My app request settings.json via factory() and then called it in a controller. The controller will be used by settings.html (ngView) and sidebar.html (ngInclude).

The json will return Boolean value that also can be changed on setting page that contain checkbox which return true if check and false if not checked. I use ngShow on the sidebar to display/hide the list items.

How can I made the sidebar to reflect the changes as I tick the checkbox?

**settings.factory.js**

```
var settingsFactory = angular.module('settingsFactory', []);

settingsFactory.factory('SettingsFilterFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {

    var settingsFactory = {};

    settingsFactory.getSettings = function () {
        return $http.get('app/data/settings.json');
    };

    return settingsFactory;
}]);
```

**controller**

```
var settingsControllers = angular.module('settingsControllers', ['settingsFactory']);

settingsControllers.controller('SettingsFilterController', ['$scope', '$http', 'SettingsFilterFactory', function ($scope, $http, SettingsFilterFactory) {

    $scope.settings;
    $scope.status;

    getSettings();

    function getSettings() {
        SettingsFilterFactory.getSettings()
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.settings = response.data;
            }, function (error) {
                $scope.status = 'Unable to load: ' + error.message;
            });
    }
}]);
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'settingsControllers']); 
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/settings', {
        title: 'Settings',
        templateUrl: 'app/components/settings/settings.html',
        controller: 'SettingsFilterController'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });
}]);
```

My **index.html** is something like this:

```
...
<body>
    <section class="sidebar">
        <div ng-include="'app/components/sidebar/sidebar.html'"></div>
    </section>

    <section class="content">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </section>
</body>
...
```

**sidebar.html**

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu" ng-controller="SettingsFilterController">
    <li ng-show"settings.hiddenMenu"><a href="#!/secret">This is secret link</a></li>
</ul>
```

**settings.html**

```
...
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="settings.hiddenMenu" ng-true-value=true ng-false-value=false> Check this to show hidden menu
</div>
...
```

Comment: it's not really clear what your complete setup is (you haven't shown the router that populates the `ng-route`), but from what you have provided, it *appears* that you are trying to use the same controller in two places.  Each time you declare the controller, you will get a new instance of the controller (they are not singletons).  changes in one instance of the controller won't be reflected in the other instance.  It is therefore not recommended to ever re-use a controller, if possible.

Comment: there are essentially 4 ways to accomplish what you are trying to do, and each has positives and negatives.  1) use a property on the `Settings` factory that each controller can see.  2) use `$scope.$broadcast` or `$emit`.  3) wrap the entire body in another controller 4) use `$rootScope`.  I ordered these approximately in my preference order.

Comment: @Claies yes you're right. I re-use the same controller. So what is the correct way to write a singleton, or do I really need a singleton in this case? So reusing controller for different view is very bad practice in AngularJS?

Comment: @Claies I will explore more on the suggestions you provided. Basically, I manage to use `$rootScope` but I think it is a bad choice since I have a lot of sidebar list items. And also I'm not sure how to declare the $rootScope based on the json request.

Comment: in general, `$rootScope` is only useful because it can be convenient.  This is not really what `$rootScope` is designed for, and using it because it is easy can lead to unexpected code complexity.  The best way to accomplish this is with properties on a service that can be injected into each controller, and into the sidebar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (untested):

**settings.factory.js**

```
var settingsFactory = angular.module('settingsFactory', []);

settingsFactory.factory('SettingsFilterFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {

    var settingsFactory = {};

    settingsFactory.getSettings = function () {
        return $http.get('app/data/settings.json');
    };

    settingsFactory.hiddenMenu= true;
    settingsFactory.someOtherSetting = {};

    return settingsFactory;
}]);
```

**sidebar controller**

```
settingsControllers.controller('SidebarController', ['$scope', '$http', 'SettingsFilterFactory', function ($scope, $http, SettingsFilterFactory) {
  //do this in each controller, so that the factory becomes a property of $scope and can be seen in the HTML
  $scope.settingsFactory = SettingsFilterFactory;
}
```

**sidebar.html**

```
 <ul class="sidebar-menu" ng-controller="SidebarController">
    <li ng-show"settingsFactory.hiddenMenu"><a href="#!/secret">This is secret link</a></li>
</ul>
```

**settings.html**

```
...
<div class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="settingsFactory.hiddenMenu" ng-true-value=true ng-false-value=false> Check this to show hidden menu
</div>
...
```

Essentially, you are binding the `settingsFactory` object which is a singleton to each `$scope` that is provided by each controller.  Each controller is able to change the property on the factory object, which is then visible in all other controllers that have injected this object.

Comment: Yeah, it works. I guess I have to move the $http to the factory() in order to get the value from backend.

Comment: Thank you so much @Claies Is this actually called singleton in AngularJS? Or this concept has different name. Might explore into it for further understanding. Thanks again for your time and help. Really appreciate it. :)

Comment: @FaizFizyRosle singleton is a generic programming pattern;  loosely, it means that a class is restricted to only creating one instance object.  Angular Dependency Injection uses the singleton pattern to ensure that no matter how many times you inject a provider, you always get the same object.  Controllers aren't providers, and aren't injected into anything else, so they don't fall under this pattern, though the providers injected into them are.